# how to disable Angular QuickStart Title when it loads first

Tags: angular, typescript

At Angular2, I can change topic of the page successfully but when I reload the page I see Angular Quick Start topic for 3 seconds after that it disappears and my specified topic can be seen. I do not want the user to see Angular Quick Start topic. I think I have to modify my setTopic settings. You can see the title implementation at the following snippet.

```
  import { BrowserModule, Title }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

 constructor (private router: Router,private fbuilder: FormBuilder,private 
 http: Http,private titleService: Title){ this.setTitle("GUI 
 Transformator");
 }

setTitle( newTitle: string) {
  this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
 }
```

Comment: Remove it from index.html title tag

Comment: thank you Babar. That solved my problem